# VirtualBox NAT over proxy

Tags: linux, virtualbox, proxy, nat

I use VirtualBox 4.1.8 on a Ubuntu 10.04 host system. I have an HTTP proxy server on the host system.

How do I configure the VirtualBox to NAT the virtual machine's network and use the HTTP proxy for all internet communication?

I know, I could use the proxy configuration on the virtual machine but this is not smart solution.

Comment: You may want to look up how to configure a "transparent proxy".

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to NAT a connection outgoing from the guest to the host.

Make sure that the proxy configuration is such that it permits connections from the IP address range the virtual host is using, then all you need to do is configure the host IP and proxy port in the virtual host proxy config.

Comment: I think he has the same problem as I have. I do not want a Host-Guest communication. I have a host where I had to configure a proxy to use get access to internet (it is working). Now I want to configure my Virtualbox Debian Guest (with an universal configuration), and no matter how I change the host's network, as long as the host has access to internet, the Guest should also have access. Most importantly, wget or curl (without any proxy configuration). In other words I want the Guest to use the Host's proxy channel (it it is authenticated).

Comment: @karatedog  You cannot hijack an authenticated proxy session from another machine, virtual or otherwise.